# Matplotlib plt.show() not showing subplot graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

Been trying to show these subplots in matplotlib but the code only works at random.

Sometimes it shows the graphs while other times it just throws the blank space.

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

```py
def min_avg_max_pol_city(num_cities = 5):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 7 , ncols = 3 , figsize=(22,22))
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 1) #Set each sub plot proportional to the total length of the plot area

    no2_min = ax[0,0]
    sub_df = df[df['pollutant_id'] == 'NO2'].sort_values('pollutant_min', ascending = True).head(num_cities)
    sns.barplot( ax = no2_min, x = sub_df.city, y = sub_df.pollutant_min)
    no2_min.set_ylabel("Pollution Level", fontsize = 14)
    no2_min.set_title("Cities with Least NO2 level", fontsize = 14)

    no2_avg = ax[0,1]
    sub_df = df[df['pollutant_id'] == 'NO2'].sort_values('pollutant_avg', ascending = False).head(num_cities)
    sns.barplot( ax = no2_avg, x = sub_df.city, y = sub_df.pollutant_avg)
    no2_avg.set_title('Cities with Average NO2 level', fontsize = 14)
    plt.show()

    no2_max = ax[0,2]
    sub_df = df[df['pollutant_id'] == 'NO2'].sort_values('pollutant_max' , ascending = False).head(num_cities)
    sns.barplot( ax = no2_max , x = sub_df.city, y = sub_df.pollutant_max)
    no2_max.set_title('Cities with Max NO2 level' , fontsize = 14)

    plt.show();

min_avg_max_pol_city(5)
```

[image]

This is a screenshot from jupyter notebook

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter-Notebooks, plt.show() is usually not required. Try

```py
return fig
```

at the end of your function `min_avg_max_pol_city()` (instead of `plt.show();`). If the return value of a notebook cell is a figure, Jupyter should render it. Remove the other `plt.show()` lines as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call `plt.show()` at the end of the code i.e., when you have plotted all subplots in the figure. For example, check how [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_star_poly.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-star-poly-py) uses `plt.show()`.